# Using SQL Tuning wizard with sp_prepexec statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, odbc, database-tuning

I am attempting to use the SQL profiler and Tuning wizard to investigate index usage in my SQL 2008 R2 database. 
The application connects to the db using ODBC. The db has not Stored Procedures and all the data is accessed using SQL statements. 
The profiler shows the statement as

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=10234
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(max),@P2 varchar(max),@P3 int,@P4 int',
N'SELECT  p.PaymentID from Payment where DivisionCode = @P1 and [...],','DM','A',1,1
select @p1
```

The tuning wizard will analyse the data and give a warning

```
49% of consumed workload has syntax errors. Check tuning log
```

The log shows the reason

> Event does not reference any tables.

or

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Payment'.

What settings do I need to use to get the tuning wizard to understand the sp_prepexec queries?
What changes must I make to the trace file to make it useable by the tuning wizard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get mine to work!  Simply comment out the `set` statement like this:

```
declare @p1 int;
--set @p1=9
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@p0 bit,@p1 varchar(8000),@p2 bit',N'select blah from blah where @p0=1 and blah.LastName=@p1',@p0=0,@p1='Kumar'
select @p1
```